# I cannot run silverlight Developer run time

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I am suddenly unable to run any of my Silverlight projects. When I try to I get a message "You need to install the latest Silverlight Developer runtime before opening Silverlight project . It next brings up a Window that says Install Silverlight 5 for Developers. When I click "Install Now". I get a message Unable to Install Silverlight, followed by another message in smaller type "A 64-bit version of Silverlight is already installed". I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Silverlight and Silverlight of Visual Studio to no avail.

Comment: Stinks.  Not much anybody can do for you. Sounds like some bad corruption in your installs.  Probably a good time to do a system refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I'm not sure but I think there is a 32 and 64 bit version of the Developer kit. It is not obvious when you look at the installed programs.

This is the key

Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe

I am editing my own answer because I was premature it saying I had fixed my problem. I want to provide as many clues as possible to anyone who follows this thread if the future. I tried a bunch of different installs until I got it to work ok. See below to what I finally ended by with.

[image]

Also I found that I needed to change my Default provider from IE to Firefox in order to be able to step through my code.